# Covering unit test for array with .find method in angular using karma and jasmine

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine

Trouble covering the following piece of code in spec file using karma and jasmine in angular 8

```
myMethod(id: number): boolean {
  const data= this.myService.getSampleData();
  return data.find(item => item.id === id).count;
}
```

spec:

```
it('should call myMethod ', () => {
    spyOn(myService,'getSampleData').and.returnValue(of([{id:1,count:10}]))
    component.myMethod(1);
});
```

It throws cannot read property .find of undefined. Although i tried spyOn(myService,'getSampleData').and.returnValue(of([{id:1,count:10}])) moving into beforeEach function as well but no luck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first issue is that you are returning an Observable using `of` when the Service seems to return an array of items.

Second, you are not doing any expect to validate something in the test.

I would do this:

```
it('should call myMethod ', () => {
    spyOn(myService,'getSampleData').and.returnValue([{id:1, count:10}]);
    expect(component.myMethod(1)).toEqual(true);
});
```

Comment: Agree. But my function return type is of boolean . 
this line 
expect(component.myMethod(1)).toEqual(10);  it throws me error TS2345: Argument of type '7' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Expected<boolean>'

Comment: My mistake. There I updated my answer. Please, try it now to see if it's works.

Comment: I want to write test for the following code, 
```public permissions = [{id: 0, value: 'fruit' }, {id: 1, value: 'vegetable'}];
this.filteredList = this.permissions.slice();
public isFiltered(permission) {
    return this.filteredList.find(item => item.id === permission.id);
} ```
Could you please help?

Comment: Sure, but I think it will be better to create a new Question where you can give me more details in order to help you

Answer (score 0):

your method expects to get an array of items. however you return Observable < Array< Item>> from your spy. try this `spyOn(myService,'getSampleData').and.returnValue([{id:1,count:10}])`