# Angular: Multiple mat-select dropdown with search functionality using mat-select-filter and adding an icon to the filter field

Tags: angular, drop-down-menu, angular-material, filtering

I want to implement `mat-select-filter` in `mat-select` module. I have added a search icon for searching the items in the dropdown based on characters entered. I have referred this [mat-select-filter](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mat-select-filter) and [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/mat-select-filter) but I was not getting the filter field.Below is the code that I've used

`search-filter.component.html`

```
 <mat-form-field class="input-permissions">
    <mat-select
      placeholder="Permissions"
      multiple
      [formControl]="permissionsControl"
    >
      <mat-select-filter
        [array]="permissions"
        (filteredreturn)="filteredList=$event"
      ></mat-select-filter>
      <mat-option
        *ngFor="let permission of permissions"
        [value]="permission.value"
      >
        {{ permission.value}}
      </mat-option>
    </mat-select>
  </mat-form-field>
```

`mat-select-filter.component.ts`

```
    export class MatSelectFilterComponent{
       permissions: {{id: 0, value: fruit},{id: 1, value: vegetable} };
       public filteredList = this.permissions.slice();
    }
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I believe you have a typo in your code `(filteredreturn="filteredList=$event"
        )`. It should be `(filteredreturn)="filteredList=$event"`

Comment: @Yuriy Kravets I have added it by mistake.Could you please provide a solution.

Comment: I added some solution for the icon. Please check it. :)

Comment: @Paul I'll check on it and added some questions in that solution.Could you please check on that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. `permissions` needs to be an `Array` and not an `object`:

   ```
   public permissions = [{id: 0, value: 'fruit' },{id: 1, value: 'vegetable'} ];
   public filteredList = this.permissions.slice();
   ```
2. You need to specify the `displayMember` on `mat-select-filter` and `filteredreturn` should be `filteredReturn`:

   ```
   <mat-select-filter [array]="permissions" (filteredReturn)="filteredList=$event" [displayMember]="'value'">
   </mat-select-filter>
   ```
3. If using a multiple select you need to do the hiding of the non filtered results yourself. Otherwise you could just iterate over `filteredList`, but in that case old selections are removed on filtering. Iterate over `permissions` instead and then hide those, which should not be shown.

   ```
   <mat-option *ngFor="let permission of permissions" [value]="permission"
       [class.hide]="!isFiltered(permission)">
       {{permission.value}}
   </mat-option>
   ```

   and the function for checking the filtered elements

   ```
   public isFiltered(permission) {
     return this.filteredList.find(item => item.id === permission.id)
   }
   ```

   and the css for hiding

   ```
   .mat-option.hide {
     display: none;
   }
   ```
4. There is no default support for adding some icon to the filter - or at least I didn't find one. Nevertheless you can solve this by using css.

   Add this to your index.html to ensure the font is loaded correctly:

   ```
   <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
   ```

   Add the following to your css. It adds an `::after` element containing the search icon as font. Take care to reduce the `width` of the `input` element by the space the icon needs (here it's `20px` `width` and `5px` `padding-left`) to ensure it's placed next to each other.

   ```
   .mat-filter-input {
     width: calc(100% - 25px) !important;
   }

   .mat-filter::after {
     content: "\e8b6";
     font-family: material icons;
     vertical-align: bottom;
     font-size: 20px;
     padding-left: 5px;
   }
   ```

   I needed to set the `encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None` within the component, since otherwise the styles had the wrong selector. I'm not sure if this is a stackblitz issue or not. Try it without it. If it works you can also remove `!important` from the `width` of the `input` element.

Here is the link to the solution on stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/mat-select-filter-zuy7ev

Comment: Thank you,I got it working. But an issue is persisting like,I have added more values in the array and applied filter & selected one value.Then again I have applied the filter & selected another value but the previous selected value would be disappeared.Please help on this.

Comment: @ChristinaVarghese I modified my solution. Check out the changes in point 3.

Comment: Thank you so much, this is working fine for me now.

Comment: Could you please help me to write the jest test case for the below code,
```public isFiltered(permission) {
  return this.filteredList.find(item => item.id === permission.id)
}```

Comment: I've actually never written angular test cases yet. But I can take a look and try it, if you tell me, what you got so far. Just fork my stackblitz solution, add your code and send the link. When you have this, it might also make sense to create a new question. In that case send me the link to the question. :) I'm curious.

Comment: Actually I've created a new question ,I'll send you the link, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62041683/unit-test-for-array-with-find-method-in-angular-using-jest . Also I've referred to the following answer, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59269563/covering-unit-test-for-array-with-find-method-in-angular-using-karma-and-jasminc.

Comment: Note: we need the matching CSS to hide the rows properly! Thanks for the solution

Comment: I tried this implementation but the performance is too poor for very large data set. I believe the reason is because the "permissions" and "filteredList" are both been loaded in the dropdown. The performance gets better if only looping through the "filteredList". If I'm wrong, please guide me to the correct the implementation. Thanks!