# Unit test for array with .find method in angular using jest

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jestjs

How to get coverage for array with .find method in angular. I'm getting trouble in the below piece of code.

sample.component.ts

```js
public permissions = [{id: 0, value: 'fruit' }, {id: 1, value: 'vegetable'}];
this.filteredList = this.permissions.slice();
public isFiltered(permission) {
    return this.filteredList.find(item => item.id === permission.id);
}
```

sample.spec.ts

```js
it('should call myMethod ', () => {
  expect(component.isFiltered(1)).toEqual(true);
});
```

I'm getting the following error ,
`TypeError: Cannot read property 'find' of undefined`

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

write it like this

```
 it('should call myMethod ', () => {
   let permissions = [{id: 0, value: 'fruit' },{id: 1, value: 'vegetable'} ];
   component.filteredList = permissions.slice();
   expect(component.isFiltered({id:1}).value).toEqual('vegetable');
 });
```

You need to give some value to `component.filteredList`

**UPDATE**

as you are using `persmissions.id` in your ts to filter you need to pass an object with property `id`(to filter by) to `isFiltered()`. Also `isFiltered` does not returns a boolean but the object (i.e. search result itself) so we check its value to be the required one

Comment: this is not working for me.Running into previous error itself.Could you please post a working code.

Comment: Happy to help :-)